# How would I go about inserting values that affect multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My schema is this:

```
Tables:
Titles ->         ID |     TitleID    | TitleName | ArtistNameFull | Length
Artists->         ID | ArtistNameRoot
ArtistRelation->  ID | TitleID | ArtistID | Relationship
```

ArtistNameFull is artist name including: "feat, with, including, featuring, presents, etc."

ArtistNameRoot is just the artist without "feat, with including, featuring, etc."

The relationship between them in ArtistRelation is in another table which has indexes 1-15 and their corresponding "suffix" essentially. As in, index 3 would be "featuring" and index 7 would be "with".

I have about 1000 rows of data that I need to insert into my tables, which is just values of (Title, Artist, length).

Methods so far:
My methods so far have been to place all this data that I need inserted into a temporary table itself and then call sql functions that select unique values between the Title table and the temporary table and then insert them, which works if I'm inserting into just the Titles table, but I also need to insert into Artists which is a little more tricky because I need to get rid of anything but the root artist. So then I tried using php to grab data from my temporary table and using regular expressions to get just the root artist, which works wonders for getting just the root artist, but connecting all this together and figuring out how to insert both into artist relation when there could already be artists from previous insertions is hard to wrap my head around.

Anyway, I guess I just need words of wisdom for if I'm going about this in a really inefficient way, or this is how it is usually done and I just have to keep going.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. And if you want to know how to fix your code, you need to post what you've tried.

Comment: this seems like something that could get very tricky. What if you have a group named "Christmas Presents", the word "presents" will look like a relationship word. Parsing stuff like this requires intelligence.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the code being wrong as I really need to know how to go about this. The question essentially is how do i insert the data that I have into my tables when Artists and ArtistRelation need to update from my insertion into titles(if this method is applied). @Barmar

Comment: Well... back to the drawing board for my regular expression code... haha thanks for that point @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is much better than SQL at manipulating strings. So keep doing that. Also using the temp table is a valid method.

You will need to use PHP to pull all of the data from the temp table.

For each result parse out the artist name and insert it into artists.

After each insert you want to get the last ID that was inserted (PDO and mysqli_ have methods for this) and then store that ID and the artist name in an array so that the ID can be used later.

Then insert the title information.

After each insert get the last ID that was inserted and use it and the artist ID to insert a record into the relations table.

Does this help?

Comment: This is a big help. Thank you!